# gnuwin32 libxml2 installation : setting several lib and include directories

Tags: windows-8, include, libxml2, mingw32, linkage

I am now compiling libxml2 on windows 8 using mingw32.

I have downloaded from here ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/ and follow the instruction found in the README file. They instruct to configure make using a javascript called configure.js. We can run the script like this:

```
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc prefix=c:\opt include=c:\opt\include lib=c:\opt\lib debug=yes
```

I guess there is a super simple and maybe obvious to this question, but how do I set several lib and include folders ? I tried separating with ";" :

```
cscript configure.js compiler=mingw zlib=yes prefix=C:\cpp\libraries\libxml2 include=C:\cpp\libraries\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include;C:\cpp\libraries\zlib1.2.3\GnuWin32\include lib=C:\cpp\libraries\iconv-1.9.2.win32\lib;C:\cpp\libraries\zlib1.2.3\GnuWin32\lib
```

but that did not work out. Did not find anything about that in the readme file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally things were not so difficult.
the javascript script create a file config.mingw that is easy to edit, in this case manually adding the paths separately with -I, in my case:

```
INCLUDE+= -IC:\cpp\libraries\iconv\GnuWin32\include -IC:\cpp\libraries\zlib1.2.3\GnuWin32\include
LIB+= -LC:\cpp\libraries\iconv\GnuWin32\lib -LC:\cpp\libraries\zlib1.2.3\GnuWin32\lib
```